# Create custom field name with two underscores in account object in salesforce

Tags: custom-field, account, name

I want to create a custom field.
The requirement says the custom field name must have double underscores (__).

The field name should be **qidc__onekeyid_ims**

But Salesforce is giving errors. The validation rules for field names are not allowing this. Giving the following error.

*Error: The custom field name you provided qidc__onekeyid_ims on object Account can only contain alphanumeric characters, must begin with a letter, cannot end with an underscore or contain two consecutive underscore characters, and must be unique across all Account fields*

I tried looking for other questions, but none of them didn't help.

Also for reference, I've seen another sandbox that has the same field name. We were trying to copy that sandbox. But in our sandbox, we cannot create it.

[image]

Is there any way I can bypass the rule and create a field using a double underscore?

Comment: Only the managed package ISV can create namespaced field names; once you install the package, you can extend the name-spaced custom object with custom fields - these field names - e.g. `onekey_ims__c` will not have a namespace as part of the field name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message is correct you cannot have two consecutive underscores in API name.

Please try by removing consecutive underscores.

qidc__onekeyid_ims : This name is there in other sandbox because it must be part of some package. If you need that you have to install that package. where qidc is the namespace.

Refer [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_plan_namespaces.htm) article for more information on namespace.
[Steps to install package.](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.distribution_installing_packages.htm&type=5)

Comment: Is there any way I can create a namespace with *qidc* and add fields in this namespace so that I can finally achieve *qidc* with 2 underscores in field 'onekeyid_ims'
The final result will be 'qidc__onekeyid_ims'.

Comment: Namespace is globally unique - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.faq_distribution_installing_what_happens_to_my.htm&type=5. You will not be able to create it. Try to install the package from other org instead of trying to create new field.

Comment: Understood. Thanks Amit.